# How to count in ruby on rails and display nothing if size is zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I am doing a simple count in rails and i want to display nothing if the size of the object am counting  is zero instead of displaying the number 0

Example includes

```
<%= @user.post.size%>
```

or `<%=@post.comments.size%>`

Any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
<% size = @user.post.size %>
<%= (size == 0) ? nil : size %>
```

or

```
<% size = @post.comments.size %>
<%= (size == 0) ? nil : size %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `<%= @post.comments.size unless @post.comments.empty? %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set the variable in the view.
<% size = @user.post.size %>

# Display size unless it is zero.
<%= size unless size.zero? %>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: `<%= size unless size.zero? %>` reads better than `<%= (size == 0) ? nil : size %>`

The first one says "return size unless size is zero." The latter says if size is equal to zero return nil else return size.

Answer (score -2):

You can check this

```
@post.comments.any?
@user.post.size.nil?
```